# OpenCV cvHaarDetectObject error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I am making a project in Visual Studio 2010 using Qt4.8.0 and OpenCV2.3.1 library. Everything is fine as long as I don't use

```
cvHaarDetectObjects()
```

function. The program was compiled and built without problems, but when I try to run the application the error 0xc000007b appears. I've done similar program in win console and this function work properly. Why am I receiving this error message? I also try to use:

```
CascadeClassifier *haar;
haar->load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
```

but it doesn't work even in console.

Example code

MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
temp = cvCreateImage(cvSize(200, 200), 8, 1);
haarface = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*) cvLoad("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
twarze = cvHaarDetectObjects(temp, haarface, storage, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(100,100));
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
class MainWindow
{
private:
    CvMemStorage *pamiec;   
    CvHaarClassifierCascade * haarface;
    IplImage *temp2;
    CvSeq *twarze;
public:
    MainWindow(void);
};
```

Maybe it something wrong with .xml files?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml exists in the current directory?
If it does not exist, then cvLoad will return NULL. Use full path for the xml file.
Also, what is error 0xc000007b? Could you post the full error description?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it exist in this directory. "Application wasn't run properly(0xc000007b). Click "OK", to close the application." When I comment line twarze = cvHaarDetectObjects(temp, haarface, storage, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(100,100)); everything is working good.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed slashes to backslashes and it works ;) `cvLoad("\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");`
EDITED: ok, it doesn't crashes. Actually I am working with 2.4.8 edition o opencv. The problem with this code is cvHaarDetectObjects that seems to be not longer supported. It is recomended to use detectMultiScale instead.